# Matlab. Change fucntion of estimate (VAR model) from maximum likelihood to ols

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

So by using this piece of code i am receiving an error: Covariance is not positive-definite.

```
[T,n] = size(Y1);
Mdl = varm(n,0);
[EstMdl,EstCoeffSEMdl] = estimate(Mdl,Y1,'X',X);
```

I checked the var-covar matrix and no negative value was found there.
After some digging i came across a solution that said that estimate uses maximum likelihood instead of ols and if the function is changed the error goes away to.
How can i change the fucntion behind the estimate VAR model?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: positive definite does not mean "has no negative values" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_symmetric_matrix

Comment: What does it mean? My professor told me to check for negative values and some other comments on previus posts suggested that.

Comment: Have you seen that I have posted a link? Having negative values will make it "non positive definite", but also being all zero, and other things. The fact that it does not have negative values doesnt make it inmediately positive-definite

Comment: Yes i am really sorry for asking, i just dint understand it entirely thatch why i asked!